# Call function with argument in another Python file

Tags: python, function

I want to print a value of returned variable (text) with functions below in a file named words.py

```
def get_text(text):
    match = gettext_pattern.search(text)
    if match:
        return match.group(1).strip()
    match = undersc_pattern.search(text)
    if match:
        return match.group(3).strip()
    
    return text

def dump_text(text):
    out1 = strip_i18n(text)
    
    print(out1)
```

Then I call it in another python file named out.py

```
from words import *

dump_text(text)
```

But then I get this output:

> name 'text' is not defined

**Question**: How to solve this problem? How can I print "out1" variable value?

Comment: Text has no value rn .

Comment: What is `text` and where is it defined?

Comment: Also it should do this dump_text(get_text('some value')). Otherwise you'll have to save the value into a global and use that.

Answer (score 0):

In your file 'out.py' you're using variable named test which is not defined, do any of the following way.

Either define variable named 'text' and assigned some data (string).

```
from words import *

test = 'sample text string'
dump_text(text)
```

or argument passed should be string.

```
from words import *

dump_text('text')
```

NOTE: It will still raise error(s) after this as there are many not defined variable and functions in words.py file like strip_i18n, gettext_pattern, etc. but your basic problem will be solved by this.

Answer (score 0):

In out.py file, you haven't defined any variable called text. Also you can't access a variable given contained in a function in another file.

Hence, declare a variable text in out.py